# how to get started with using `GridView` in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to get started with using `GridView` in ASP.net?

Comment: heres a tip: use asp.net mvc :) seriously though, you avoid the horrendous viewstate, page lifecycle etc. AND you get a better chance of learning HTML and CSS properly (not guaranteed tho). not really a tip&trick so posted as comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grid view is pretty slick especially in asp.net. You can check all the gridview tutorials on [ASP DATA TUTORIALS.](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/). it is the perfect place to start learning asp.net. If you don't want to learn then you can always add a sql database, insert a grid view and connect it to the data base via a datasource. Then you can play around with it. However i will strongly recommend those tutorials as they contain all tips and tricks you want to know. You can ask more questions here, i will be glad to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a few blog posts on the GridView:

1. Multiple Row Selections with CheckBoxes.
2. Checking All Rows Using Client-Side Script.
3. Attaching upload files to a record.
4. Sort Column Arrow Performance.
5. How to Work With a GridView Row in JavaScript.

All can be found [here.](http://blog.digitaltools.com/search.aspx?q=GridView)

Answer (score 1):

And I inherited from the GridView to create the GridViewTree - a multi-column treeview server control.  So reviewing this might give you some other ideas.

It can be found [here.](http://www.digitaltools.com/GVT.aspx)